# Fetch data from columns using max over another column using Oracle analytic functions

Tags: oracle, oracle-analytics

I need to fetch the sum between bal and res columns for each different account (acc) using the max(timestamp), look at this:

```
  ID    ACC BAL RES TIMESTAMP
  --------------------------
  1 100 70  0   1430238709
  2 101 4   0   1430238710
  3 102 0   0   1430238720
  4 103 3   1   1430238721
  5 100 22  1   1430238731
  6 101 89  0   1430238732
  7 102 101 1   1430238742
  8 103 105 1   1430238753
  9 100 106 0   1430238763
 10 101 100 1   1430238774
 11 102 1   1   1430238784
 12 103 65  0   1430238795
```

What I need is for `MAX(timestamp) <= 1430238763`, the `sum: bal + res` grouped by acc like this:

```
ACC TOT
-------
100 106
101 89
102 102
103 106
```

I know how to do it using subqueries, but I would like to try Analytics.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Select * from (
  Select t.*, max(TIMESTAMP) over (partition by id) mx
from tab t
)
where mx=TIMESTAMP;

hth

Answer (score 0):

your query is not solve without sub query.

```
select acc,sum(bal + res) from table_name where timestamp in 
(select acc,max(timestamp) from table_Name group by acc having hax(timestamp)<=1430238763)
```

Regards.